# search exact value in tr using tblsorter

Tags: c#, asp.net, tablesorter, exact-match

```
$('#EmpDetailsGrid').on('filterEnd filterReset ', function () {              
    var c = this.config,
    fr = c.filteredRows;

    if (fr === 0) {
        c.$table.find('.noData').remove();
        c.$table.append([
        // "remove-me" class added to rows that are not to be included 
        // in the cache when updating   
            '<tr class="noData remove-me" role="alert" aria-live="assertive">',
            '<td style="background: #ccc;" colspan="' + c.columns + '" class="text-center">No Data Found</td>',
            '</tr>'
        ].join(''));
    } else {                  
        c.$table.find('.noData').remove();                
    }
}).tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    widgets: ['zebra', 'scroller', 'columns', 'stickyHeaders', 'filter'],
    dateFormat: "mmddyyyy",
    usNumberFormat: false,
    sortReset: true,
    sortRestart: true,
    widthFixed: true,
    widgetOptions: {
        scroller_height: 200,
        scroller_barWidth: 17,
        scroller_jumpToHeader: true,
        filter_childRows: true
    },
    headers: { 5: { filter: false, sorter: false } },
});
```

I am searching `empdept` is 'it' and show only exact 'it' not show 'it-3d',it-2d','it-vfx',etc...and allow '-' symbol when combination searching dept

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking here, but maybe a [custom filter function](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-custom.html) is what you are looking for? If not, please provide more details and/or [modify this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/bbxxomhx/).

Comment: Ahh, from the duplicate question I saw the image.. maybe what you want is the "filter-exact" class name ([ref](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter.html#classes))